# Set android datepicker date limits

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I am using datePicker in android to display images based on user selected dates. I need to limit said dates to certain days for instance Jan 1st 2010 to Dec 31st 2010. Simple as that i thought but no where can i find the answer on how to limit these dates.

Does anyone know how to limit the dates for Android DatePicker

Comment: I managed to programatically set the min, max selectable dates, & also set the current ( default ) date for the DatePicker View : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421874/how-to-get-the-date-set-in-the-datepicker-widget-in-android/7961268#7961268

Answer (score 8):

You can just set :

```
dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```

and

```
dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
```

where dateDialog is a

```
new DatePickerDialog()
```

and the param type to set for MaxDate and MinDate is a `long`

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late to answer, but the it is easy to set the `min` and `max` date for `DatePickerDialog`. **Works for All Android versions**. Simply you need to return the `DatePickerDialog` based on Android version

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch ( id )
    {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            DatePickerDialog dialog = null;
            if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB )
            {
                dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate)
                    {
                        mTextView.setText(selectedDate + "/" + selectedMonth + 1 + "/" + selectedYear);
                    }
                }, year, month - 1, date);
                Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(currentDate.getTimeInMillis());
                //If you need you can set min date too
            }
            else
            {
                dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDate)
                    {
                        mTextView.setText(selectedDate + "/" + selectedMonth + 1 + "/" + selectedYear);
                    }
                }, year, month - 1, date)
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)
                    {
                        if ( year <= maxYear && month + 1 <= maxMonth && date <= maxDate ) //meets your criteria
                        {
                            view.updateDate(year, month, date); //update the date picker to selected date
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth - 1, maxDate); // or you update the date picker to previously selected date
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            return dialog;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to implement your own `DatePicker`. The logic behind this would be: "Only a few developers would ever limit the `DatePicker` so they have to implement the functionality themselfs."

Comment: Also for XML there are some additional properties available like endYear beginYear, you can use that for bounds.

Comment: where would i find the information on the endYear beginYear, sounds like that would work pretty nicely. 
I was afraid of the answer implement my own, hopefully this xml properties will pan out.

Comment: the endYear and beginYear bounds only work with widget not the actual datePicker dialog i am using. I will look to see how to implement the widget instead, unless anyone can offer info on how to apply bounds to the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Why you should not design new layout like DatePicker with customoption. You can do with Spinners and Forloops.

Answer (score 0):

U can achieve this by typing a simple line

```
mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mcurrentDate.add(Calendar.MONTH,6);
        mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mcurrentDate.getTimeInMillis());
```