# How to get the date from the DatePicker widget in Android?

Tags: android, datepicker

I use a `DatePicker` widget in Android for the user to set a date, and want to get the date value when a confirm button is clicked, how can I do that?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
 int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
 int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
 int year = datePicker.getYear();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when updating the date picker values in the UI.  It gives me the value it started with

Comment: Right. Please try to set OnDateSetListener to datePicker.

Comment: This worked for me. I set these values like this String day = String.valueof(datePicker.getDayOfMonth(); It so far works perfectly because it converts the ints to strings in my case for inserts to a sql database.

Answer (score 23):

I manged to set the MinDate & the MaxDate programmatically like this :

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    int maxYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 20; // this year ( 2011 ) - 20 = 1991
    int maxMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int maxDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    int minYear = 1960;
    int minMonth = 0; // january
    int minDay = 25;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_account);
        BirthDateDP = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.create_account_BirthDate_DatePicker);
        BirthDateDP.init(maxYear - 10, maxMonth, maxDay, new OnDateChangedListener()
        {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            if (year < minYear)
                view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);

                if (monthOfYear < minMonth && year == minYear)
                view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);

                if (dayOfMonth < minDay && year == minYear && monthOfYear == minMonth)
                view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);


                if (year > maxYear)
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

                if (monthOfYear > maxMonth && year == maxYear)
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);

                if (dayOfMonth > maxDay && year == maxYear && monthOfYear == maxMonth)
                view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
        }}); // BirthDateDP.init()
    } // activity
```

it works fine for me, enjoy :)

Comment: i want to do opposite of it, means min date will be current date and max date will be any date greater than current date. How to do that. Any help will be highly appreciated.I tried but getting some problem.Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675984/date-picker-with-max-and-minimum-date-in-ondatechanged-in-android-1-5

Answer (score 15):

If you are using **Kotlin**, you can define an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) for `DatePicker`:

```
fun DatePicker.getDate(): Date {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth)
    return calendar.time
}
```

Then, it's just: `datePicker.getDate()`. As if it had always existed.

Answer (score 5):

you mean that you want to add DatePicker widget into your apps.

Global variable declaration into your activity class:

```
private Button mPickDate;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
```

write down this code into onCreate() function:

```
//date picker presentation
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);//button for showing date picker dialog 
    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID); }
    });

    // get the current date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    // display the current date
    updateDisplay();
```

write down those function outside of onCreate() function:

```
//return date picker dialog
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}

//update month day year
private void updateDisplay() {
    mBodyText.setText(//this is the edit text where you want to show the selected date
        new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
        .append(mYear).append("-")
        .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
        .append(mDay).append(""));


            //.append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            //.append(mDay).append("-")
            //.append(mYear).append(" "));
}

// the call back received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();
        }
};
```

Comment: Really a good one, you can also implement it if you require birthday input in an EditText

Comment: Please note: onCreateDialog is deprecated, you can create a DialogFragment to use

Answer (score 4):

you can also use this code...

```
datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.schedule_datePicker);
int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
int year = datePicker.getYear();


SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
String strDate = dateFormatter.format(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) class has methods for getting the month, year, day of month. Or you can use an [OnDateChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html).

Answer (score 1):

U can also use te Calendar.GregorianCalendar java class

```
    GregorianCalendar calendarBeg=new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(),
        datePicker.getMonth(),datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
    Date begin=calendarBeg.getTime();
```