# How do I set the current date in a DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

I need to be able to choose date and time in my application
It should either be done by using a dialog, or starting a new intent.

The way I have done it now, is that I have started a new intent, since I need to set both date and time.

My problem is that I need to set the current date on the `Datepicker` (This is possible with the `Timepicker` using `setCurrentHour` and `setCurrentMinute`) onCreate, and set that as a lower boundary.

I can't find any functions in the Android API for doing this with the `DatePicker`.

Anyone have a suggestion to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: 
Important: The `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` must be in the same dialog/intent

Comment: Here is how to set the current date & set the min & the max selectable date : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421874/how-to-get-the-date-set-in-the-datepicker-widget-in-android/7961268#7961268

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Straight to code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog dialog =
    new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: then use these dialog always :)

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);     

// set current date into datepicker
datepicker.init(year, month, day, null);
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are simply looking for the equivalent of `setCurrentHour()` and `setCurrentMinute()` on `TimePicker`, but on `DatePicker` - see [updateDate (int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#updateDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29) on `DatePicker`.

```
DatePicker mDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
mDatePicker.updateDate(1994, 6, 12);
// Sets date displayed on DatePicker to 12th June 1994
```

Comment: For some reason, DatePicker in `DatePickerDialog` does not update currently showed year if I show it, then update DatePicker, and then show it again. I had to recreate the dialog again in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the current date through the Calendar class.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.get(Calendar.WHATDOYOUNEED);
```

Feed it's `get()` method with different parameters to customize your query.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial for the DatePicker seems to do exactly this?

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

Refer to:

```
    // get the current date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // display the current date (this method is below)
    updateDisplay();
```

Comment: nah, i want to set the date on the datePicker, not a textview

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/using-android-date-picker/) it has pics to demonstrate.

Comment: i also need to set the time in the same dialog or intent