# My current date not showing in edittext

Tags: android, datepicker

this is my simple code to get current date and display in a text filed.but the current date is not showing i could not find any error.Please help me out geeks

```
  month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            year1 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            Log.d("8999",month+" "+day+" "+year1);
                            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Reminder.this,
                                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int 

        year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                                et_cal.setText("" + dayOfMonth + " - " + monthOfYear+1 + " - " + year);
                                                Toast.makeText(Reminder.this, "" + dayOfMonth + " - " + monthOfYear + " - " + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        },year1,month,day);
                                datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: That `Toast` is appeared?

Comment: yes it worked>but only the current date is not displaying

Comment: check text color of your edit text .

Comment: By current date you mean today's date ?

Comment: Try this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803229/android-studio-datepicker-not-showing-calendar-from-current-year/39803400#39803400](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803229/android-studio-datepicker-not-showing-calendar-from-current-year/39803400#39803400)

Comment: Current date or selected date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one line in code If current date is display wrong

```
month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    year1 = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Log.d("8999",month+" "+day+" "+year1);
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(SearchViewActivity.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int
                        year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    int curr_month = monthOfYear+1;

                    et_cal.setText("" + dayOfMonth + " - " + curr_month+" - " + year);
                    Toast.makeText(SearchViewActivity.this, "" + dayOfMonth + " - " + curr_month + " - " + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },year1,month,day);
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

If date not showing then please provide your XML layout file then i elaborate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DatePickerDialog` doesn't appear to actually be doing anything. You are not setting any of your `Calendar` fields with the date that the user selected as the date. You are simply outputting the `Calendar` fields as they existed prior to your DatePickerDialog listener firing.

I would do it like this:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            et_cal.setText("" + dayOfMonth + " - " + monthOfYear+1 + " - " + year);
        }
    };
```