# String to datepicker

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am able to use a `DatePicker` widget to save a Date to a String as follows:

```
dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);
int day = dpResult.getDayOfMonth();
int month = dpResult.getMonth() -1;
int year = dpResult.getYear();


SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
String strDate = dateFormatter.format(d);
```

This provides a String, e.g. for 09 Apr 2016: `04-09-3916`

My question is how do I reverse this, to get the String value to show back in my DatePicker?

I have tried the following code:

```
String[] parts = strDate.split("-");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
String part3 = parts[2];

month = Integer.parseInt(part1);
day = Integer.parseInt(part2);
year = Integer.parseInt(part3);

dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
```

but the DatePicker shows a date of 31 Dec 2100, not 09 Apr 2016

Comment: Can't you use the setters, since you used the getters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451837/how-do-i-set-the-current-date-in-a-datepicker) SO question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
datepicker.init(year, month, day, null);
```

Comment: I also added `int yeara = Integer.parseInt(part3);` and `year = yeara - 1900;`