# How to update date month and year in datepicker andriod studio kotlin

Tags: kotlin, datepicker

> Day,year and month using these given values after being updated.
>       I want them to use updated values please help.

```
var day = 1  
var month = 1  
var year = 1999  
val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog,
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, selyear,
   monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

    day = dayOfMonth
    month = monthOfYear
    year = selyear
    tv.text = "$day - $month - $year"  /*printing day month year*/

   }, year, month, day
 )

  dpd.show()

   val pday = 30 - day   /* day = 1(Not the chosen value)*/
   val pmonth = 12 - month  
   val pyear = 2019 - year
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the current date in a DatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451837/how-do-i-set-the-current-date-in-a-datepicker)

Comment: No this is not what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the variable declarations from `val` to `var` and update them inside the listener:

```
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        var day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        var month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        var year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)

        val dpd = DatePickerDialog(
            this,
            android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog,
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, selyear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                day = dayOfMonth
                month = monthOfYear + 1
                year = selyear
                tv.text = "$day - $month - $year"

            }, year, month, day
        )

        dpd.show()
```

Comment: I just wanted to update date month and year according to the selected date in datepicker

Comment: @PranjalRawat and what is the problem?

Comment: i wanted to change the value of date month and year according to the select date on date picker but that's not working

Comment: You still don't say **what** is not working. Is the app crashing? Is `birthDate` not updated?

Comment: the app is working fine but in the date picker dialog box i am not able to get access to the new selected dates

Comment: Post the layout of your activity.

Comment: the date month and year are showing current dates and i wanted the dates selected in datepicker

Comment: I tested the code: when the datepicker opens the current date is selected. If I choose a date from the datepicker and click ok then the date I selected updates the textview. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: you mean if you print date month and year the selected dates are printed

Comment: The textview shows the date that I selected from the datepicker.

Comment: Do you also want the variables day, month and year to change to the selected date?

Comment: Hey forbas can we talk in gmail as i have some problem in my project

Comment: @PranjalRawat I don't do any communicating outside of SO. If you have any problem/question about programming post it, with all the relevant info and code and if I can, I will provide an answer.

Comment: How can i provide you the project files

Comment: when i am subtracting day, month or year from any number and putting them in new var in this case day, month and year are using there previous values

Comment: var pday = 30 - day

Comment: Put: `var pday = 0 var pmonth = 0 var pyear = 0` before the listener and `pday = 30 - day pmonth = 12 - month pyear = 2019 - year` inside the listener, after `tv.text = "$day - $month - $year"`

Comment: The updated values can be used outside the listener after the dialog is closed, because before they have their original values. If you want to use these values anywhere in the class, put their declarations at the class level.

Comment: The dialog closes when `OnDateSetListener()` is executed and there you set the values of these variables. Just because you put the lines after the listener this does not mean that the listener has been executed.

Comment: Help me to create a class to use them outside

Comment: The comments section is not the place to get answers, just for clarifications. You must post a new question with all the relevant code, describe what you have tried and explain what you exactly need.

Comment: I just update my question so you can now add a answer to it

Comment: For the code you updated I gave you the answer: the variables must be inside the listener so they get their values when the user clicks the ok button of the dialog.

Comment: This is not how it works here in SO. You can't post questions one after another in the same post. You must post a new question where you explain in details what you need and what you have tried so far.