# getdate from datepicker android

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I want to get date from datepicker widget in android I have tried with this

```
Date date1= (Date) new Date
   (dpBirthDate.getYear(), dpBirthDate.getMonth(), dpBirthDate.getDayOfMonth());
date1  = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date1.toString());
```

But I get a date like this `mon 7 dec 2011 time` ... and all I want to get is the `yyyy-MM-dd` format to store it in the database.

I tried also to concat the *year-month-day* like this but the problem is for example today 
*2011-12-7* the day should  be 07 to be valid

Could you help me please.

Comment: Wow, srsly DatePicker does not have a method getDate??? Android/Google cmon.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I use this:

```
    /**
 * 
 * @param datePicker
 * @return a java.util.Date
 */
public static java.util.Date getDateFromDatePicker(DatePicker datePicker){
    int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = datePicker.getMonth();
    int year =  datePicker.getYear();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);

    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: This largely worked for me, except I needed to define the DatePicker as a android.widget.DatePicker instead. Thanks :)

Comment: If you are using **Kotlin**, you can do it even in a more elegant [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53053337/4071001).

Comment: Thanks a lot, man.

Answer (score 14):

You should use [`SimpleDateFormat.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert that `Date` object to a `String`, like this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateString = sdf.format(date1);
```

I think you just had it backwards. You need to use `format` to go from Date to String, and `parse` to go from a String to a Date.

Comment: changed the code like this Date date1= (Date) new Date(dpBirthDate.getYear(), dpBirthDate.getMonth(), dpBirthDate.getDayOfMonth());
      dates =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date1); and what I got 3911-12-07 whats wrong

Comment: Well then check what the year of the Date object is before you pass it in

Comment: how can I fix the Date format please help ! I always get the date strats with 3911

Comment: Then you are creating the Date object incorrectly. As I said, you should debug what the value actually is. If you look at the documentation of [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) you see that the year you pass in must be "the year minus 1900", so that is probably your error. Java's `Date` object has to be handled with care.

Comment: thank you now its clear I should do 3911 -1900 to get the proper year 2011

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but i struggled to find it. So for posterity

Scenario: A View needs the date in yyyy-mm-dd

```
    date_field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_date);
        date_field.setFocusable(false); // disable editing of this field
        date_field.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                chooseDate();
            }
        });

 private void chooseDate() {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePicker =
            new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(final DatePicker view, final int year, final int month,
                                      final int dayOfMonth) {

                    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                    String dateString = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

                    date_field.setText(dateString); // set the date
                }
            }, year, month, day); // set date picker to current date

        datePicker.show();

        datePicker.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(final DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

If your formatting was simple as numbers,

eg: **dd/MM/yyyy**

You can use the **Kotlin** way:

```
val dp = binding.datePicker
val date =  "${dp.dayOfMonth.let { if(it < 10) "0$it" else it }}/${dp.month.plus(1).let { if(it < 10) "0$it" else it }}/${dp.year}"
```