# How to set start time and end time with an interval of 30 minutes in TimePicker Android?

Tags: android

I am working on DatePicker and TimePicker in android. I am getting start time and and time from server. I can set max date and min date programmatically using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421874/how-to-get-the-date-set-in-the-datepicker-widget-in-android/7961268#7961268)

I want to set min time (07:00 ) and max time (10:00) in timepicker and maintain an interval of 30 minutes. I tried using [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580216/android-timepicker-minutes-to-15)

What i need is to set timepicket with min 07:00 and max time =10:00 and intervals 
07:00,07:30, 08:00 etc.

Here is the code same `

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TimePicker pn = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tp_powernap);

    pn.setCurrentHour(7);
    pn.setCurrentMinute(0);
    System.out.println("timepicker erstellt");
    pn.setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    System.out.println("Tastatur geblockt");
    pn.setOnTimeChangedListener(StartTimeChangedListener);
    System.out.println("starttimechangedlistener");
    pn.setIs24HourView(false);
}


private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener StartTimeChangedListener =
    new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        updateDisplay(view, hourOfDay, minute);          
    }
};

private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener NullTimeChangedListener =
    new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    }
};



private void updateDisplay(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    int nextMinute = 0;
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(NullTimeChangedListener);
    if (minute >= 45 && minute <= 59) 
        nextMinute = 45;  
    else if (minute  >= 30) 
        nextMinute = 30;
    else if (minute >= 15) 
        nextMinute = 15;
    else if (minute > 0) 
        nextMinute = 0; 
    else { 
        nextMinute = 45; 
    }

    if (minute - nextMinute == 1) {
        if (minute >= 45 && minute <= 59) 
            nextMinute = 00; 
        else if(minute  >= 30) 
            nextMinute = 45;
        else if(minute >= 15) 
            nextMinute = 30;
        else if(minute > 0) 
            nextMinute = 15; 
        else { 
            nextMinute = 15; 
        }
    }

    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(nextMinute);

    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(StartTimeChangedListener);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference (this is a old question). The interval can be implemented using the following hack:

```
Class<?> classForid = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
Field field = classForid.getField("minute");

NumberPicker mMinuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) timePicker
                    .findViewById(field.getInt(null));
mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
mMinuteSpinner.setMaxValue((60 / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) - 1);
List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) {
    displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
}
mMinuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues
                    .toArray(new String[0]));
```

see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580216/android-timepicker-minutes-to-15)

Start- and Endtime can be set in similar manner but there are problems with the AM/PM Flag. If you don't use am/pm but instead always show the time in 24-hours format your problem is solved ;-)

```
        if (startHour != -1 && endHour != -1) {
            Field field = classForid.getField("hour");
            NumberPicker hourSpinner = (NumberPicker) timePicker
                    .findViewById(field.getInt(null));
            hourSpinner.setMinValue(startHour);
            hourSpinner.setMaxValue(endHour);
            List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (timePicker.is24HourView()) {
                for (int i = startHour; i <= endHour; ++i) {
                    displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = startHour; i <= 12; ++i) {
                    displayedValues.add(String.format("%d", i));
                }
                for (int i = 1; i <= endHour % 12; ++i) {
                    displayedValues.add(String.format("%d", i));
                }
            }
            hourSpinner.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues
                    .toArray(new String[0]));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.NumberPicker
import android.widget.TimePicker
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import java.lang.reflect.Field
import java.util.*


class TimePickerInterval @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TimePicker(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var MINUTE_INTERVAL = 1
    private var MIN_MINUTE= 0
    private var MAX_MINUTE = 60
    override fun getCurrentMinute(): Int {
        return super.getCurrentMinute() * MINUTE_INTERVAL
    }

    override fun getMinute(): Int {
        return super.getMinute() * MINUTE_INTERVAL
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        setUp()
    }

    private fun setUp() {
        try {
            val classForid = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R\$id")
            val field: Field = classForid.getField("minute")
            val mMinuteSpinner = findViewById<NumberPicker>(field.getInt(null))
            mMinuteSpinner.minValue = MIN_MINUTE
            mMinuteSpinner.maxValue = MAX_MINUTE / MINUTE_INTERVAL - 1
            val displayedValues: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
            var i = 0
            while (i < 60) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i))
                i += MINUTE_INTERVAL
            }
            mMinuteSpinner.displayedValues = displayedValues.toTypedArray()

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun setOnTimeChangedListener(onTimeChangedListener: OnTimeChangedListener) {
        super.setOnTimeChangedListener { tp, hour, minute ->
            onTimeChangedListener.onTimeChanged(tp, hour, minute * MINUTE_INTERVAL)
        }
    }

    override fun setMinute(minute: Int) {
        super.setMinute(minute / MINUTE_INTERVAL)
    }
    fun setMinMinute(min: Int) {
        MIN_MINUTE = min
        setUp()
    }
    fun setMaxMinute(max: Int) {
        MAX_MINUTE = max
        setUp()
    }
   fun setMinuteInterval(interval: Int) {
        MINUTE_INTERVAL = interval
        setUp()
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("time_picker_set_minute_interval")
        fun setMinuteInterval(view: TimePickerInterval, interval: Int?) {
            interval?.let {
                view.setMinuteInterval(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```