# How to find out array of time range in between start time and and time in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a time range in between two times. I am able to do it in PHP
This code gives the array of times with 30 minutes interval when i supply start time , end time and interval. Below is the php script.

```
//timerange.php


   <?php 

/** 
* create_time_range  
*  
* @param mixed $start start time, e.g., 9:30am or 9:30 
* @param mixed $end   end time, e.g., 5:30pm or 17:30 
* @param string $by   1 hour, 1 mins, 1 secs, etc. 
* @access public 
* @return void 
*/ 
function create_time_range($start, $end, $by='30 mins') { 

   $start_time = strtotime($start); 
   $end_time   = strtotime($end); 

   $current    = time(); 
   $add_time   = strtotime('+'.$by, $current); 
   $diff       = $add_time-$current; 

   $times = array(); 
   while ($start_time < $end_time) { 
       $times[] = $start_time; 
       $start_time += $diff; 
    } 
  $times[] = $start_time; 
  return $times; 
 } 

  // create array of time ranges 
  $times = create_time_range('9:30', '17:30', '30 mins'); 

   // more examples 
  // $times = create_time_range('9:30am', '5:30pm', '30 mins'); 
   // $times = create_time_range('9:30am', '5:30pm', '1 mins'); 
 // $times = create_time_range('9:30am', '5:30pm', '30 secs'); 
 // and so on 

// format the unix timestamps 
   foreach ($times as $key => $time) { 
     $times[$key] = date('g:i:s', $time); 
  } 


      print '<pre>'. print_r($times, true).'</pre>'; 
    /* 
   * result 
   * 
    Array 
  ( 
  [0] => 9:30:00 
  [1] => 10:00:00 
  [2] => 10:30:00 
  [3] => 11:00:00 
  [4] => 11:30:00 
  [5] => 12:00:00 
  [6] => 12:30:00 
  [7] => 1:00:00 
  [8] => 1:30:00 
  [9] => 2:00:00 
  [10] => 2:30:00 
  [11] => 3:00:00 
  [12] => 3:30:00 
  [13] => 4:00:00 
   [14] => 4:30:00 
   [15] => 5:00:00 
   [16] => 5:30:00 
 ) 

  */ 

     ?>
```

I need to do the equivalent in JAVA  code. I think this would be helpful to others.

Comment: Java is not an acronym and should not be set in all-caps.

Comment: Use `LocalTime` and `Duration` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and it won’t be that hard (much easier than with `Calendar` and the other poorly designed and long outdated date-time classes used in most of the answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to do this using only java APIs is to use the Calendar class

```
    Date startTime = ...//start
    Date endTime = ../end
    ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<String>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(startTime);
    while(calendar.getTime().before(endTime)) {
         calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
         times.add(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }
```

Comment: its working, but it gives complete date and time .I need like 10:00, 10:30, 11:00 etc. can you give exact format to return time as i mentioned above.My php script gives as: [0] => 9:30:00 
  [1] => 10:00:00 
  [2] => 10:30:00 
  [3] => 11:00:00 
  [4] => 11:30:00 
  [5] => 12:00:00 
  [6] => 12:30:00

Comment: Ok I changed it to only display the time part, try it now

Comment: can you have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623058/how-to-set-start-time-and-end-time-with-an-interval-of-30-minutes-in-timepicker

Comment: i need to do it with timepicker in android.

Comment: One problem there, it does not include first value, it starts from 10:00 ,i need both inclusive means, my array should be like above php function array output

Comment: the first value is actually included, you just need to set the start time 30 minutes before the first value or just reverse the 2 lines in the while loop

Answer (score 3):

I modified MahdeTo answer to include start time like this.  I am posting whole code below.

```
enter code here






  import java.text.DateFormat;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Calendar;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

 public class TimeRange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
    //
    // A string of time information
    //
    String time = "9:00:00";
    String time1 = "21:00:00";

    //
    // Create an instance of SimpleDateFormat with the specified
    // format.
    //
    DateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    try {

        Date date = sdf1.parse(time);            
        System.out.println("Date and Time: " + date);


         Date date1 = sdf1.parse(time1);            
        System.out.println("Date and Time1: " + date1);



ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<String>();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);

   if (calendar.getTime().before(date1)){
   times.add(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
  System.out.println("Initial time:  "+times);



    while(calendar.getTime().before(date1)) {

   calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
   times.add(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
   System.out.println(times);
}

 }


      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably doing this using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It has a `Duration` class which you can add to a `DateTime` object using the `.plus()` method.

Take the base datetime, build your duration, cycle over it and add the datetimes into an array, just like you do (well, in fact, the code below uses a `Set`, since all objects will be unique).

Sample code:

```
public final class JodaTest
{
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT
        = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final DateTime start = FORMAT.parseDateTime("09:30");
        final DateTime end = FORMAT.parseDateTime("17:30");

        final Duration duration = Minutes.minutes(30).toStandardDuration();

        final Set<DateTime> set = new LinkedHashSet<DateTime>();

        DateTime d = new DateTime(start);

        do {
            set.add(d);
            d = d.plus(duration);
        } while (d.compareTo(end) <= 0);

        for (final DateTime dt: set)
            System.out.println(FORMAT.print(dt));

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: i need this logic later for android app. I do know whether JODA time works for android or not.

Comment: It does. I use it in an android application, too.

Comment: check my answer to use only standard java classes

Comment: @MahdeTo which doesn't prevent my solution to work, so why vote it down?

Comment: sorry miss clicked and for some reason i can't remove it because its 2 hours ago :S

Answer (score 1):

This is the version if you have the end time the day after.

> With DateTimeFormatter

```
    String time = "18:30-00:30";

    String startTime = time.split("-")[0];
    String endTime = time.split("-")[1];

    ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<>();

    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm");

    LocalDateTime localT0 = LocalDateTime.parse(startTime).atDate(today);

    LocalDateTime localT1 = LocalDateTime.parse(endTime).atDate(today);

    if (localT0.isAfter(localT1)){

        localT1 = localT1.plusDays(1);
    }

    while (localT0.isBefore(localT1)){

        times.add(localT0.format(dateTimeFormatter));
        localT0 = localT0.plusMinutes(30);
    }

    System.out.println(times.toString());
```

> With SimpleDateFormat

```
            String time = "18:30-00:30";                    

            String startTime = time.split("-")[0];
            String endTime = time.split("-")[1];
            ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<>();

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

            String day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(calendar.getTime());

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm");
            Date time1 = null;
            Date time2 = null;

            try {
                time1 = sdf.parse(day + "-" + startTime);
                time2 = sdf.parse(day + "-" + endTime);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            calendar.setTime(time1);

            calendar1.setTime(time2);

            if (calendar.getTime().after(calendar1.getTime())){

               calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

            }

            while(calendar.getTime().before(calendar1.getTime())) {
                times.add(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            }

            System.out.println(times.toString());
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @OleV.V. You are right. Check if there is a simplest solution

Comment: There are other ways, but possibly not simpler. I might have tried to get through without using `LocalDateTime`, but it would have involved some trickery and might have ended up harder to read. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Two suggestions, though: (1) Keep `LocalTime` or `LocalDateTime` objects in your list, not strings. (2) Don’t use the formatter. Declare `LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();` and then set `LocalDateTime localT0 = LocalTime.parse(startTime).atDate(today);` and similarly for `localT1`.