# How to restrict user to set date based on other date from date picker in android

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, android-datepicker

I have 2 date-picker in one activity. What i want to do is when user try to select date from second date-picker then that date should greater than first date-picker's date otherwise it should show alert dialog.

So below is my code.

```
public class Assignment_Create extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

DataManipulator dataManipulator;
static final int DIALOG_ID = 1;

ImageView imageViewDateAssign, imageViewDueDate, imageViewSubmit;
TextView textViewDtAssign, textViewDueDt;
EditText editTextTitle, editTextDesc;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
int cDay, cMonth, cYear;

private TextView activeDateDisplay;
private Calendar activeDate;

// Update database
String updateId;
public boolean isEdit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.assignment_create);

    imageViewDateAssign = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dateassign);
    imageViewDueDate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.duedate);
    imageViewSubmit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    textViewDtAssign = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDateAssign);
    textViewDueDt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDueDate);

    editTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    editTextDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);

    isEdit = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isEdit");
    updateId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idNo");

    if (isEdit) {
        editTextTitle.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(
                "AsmntTitle"));
        editTextDesc
                .setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("AsmntDesc"));
    }

    Code.AssignDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Code.DueDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    imageViewDateAssign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showDateDialog(textViewDtAssign, Code.AssignDate);
        }
    });

    imageViewDueDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            showDateDialog(textViewDueDt, Code.DueDate);
        }
    });

    imageViewSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

    updateDisplay(textViewDtAssign, Code.AssignDate);
    updateDisplay(textViewDueDt, Code.DueDate);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.submit:

        Code.title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        Code.description = editTextDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        Code.diff = Code.DueDate.getTimeInMillis()
                - Code.AssignDate.getTimeInMillis();
        Code.days = Code.diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        Code.strDays = String.valueOf(Code.days);

        Date assignDate = new Date(Code.AssignDate.getTimeInMillis());
        Date dueDate = new Date(Code.DueDate.getTimeInMillis());

        if (dueDate.before(assignDate) || dueDate.equals(assignDate)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBattery = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Assignment_Create.this);
            myDialogBattery.setTitle("How to use Less Battery");
            myDialogBattery.setMessage("hahahahahaha");
            myDialogBattery.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        }
                    });
            myDialogBattery.show();
        }

        if (isEdit) {
            this.dataManipulator = new DataManipulator(this);
            this.dataManipulator.update(updateId);
            this.dataManipulator.close();
        } else {
            this.dataManipulator = new DataManipulator(this);
            this.dataManipulator.insert(Code.title, Code.description,
                    Code.strDays);
            this.dataManipulator.close();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Details are saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Assignment Created Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Assignment_Create.this.finish();
        break;
    }
}

private void updateDisplay(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
    dateDisplay.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("-")
            .append(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("-")
            .append(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void showDateDialog(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
    activeDateDisplay = dateDisplay;
    activeDate = date;
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}

private OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        activeDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        activeDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        activeDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateDisplay(activeDateDisplay, activeDate);

        unregisterDateDisplay();
    }
};

private void unregisterDateDisplay() {
    activeDateDisplay = null;
    activeDate = null;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener,
                activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(
                activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        break;
    }
}
}
```

I have tried with the following link but not getting solution as i want

[how to not allow user select past date in datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494334/how-to-not-allow-user-select-past-date-in-datepicker)

[Setting upper and lower date limits to date picker dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029361/setting-upper-and-lower-date-limits-to-date-picker-dialog)

[How to set min-max age limit with datepicker android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871173/how-to-set-min-max-age-limit-with-datepicker-android)

[Date Picker with max and minimum date in onDateChanged() in Android 1.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675984/date-picker-with-max-and-minimum-date-in-ondatechanged-in-android-1-5)

so i am setting date, now when user click on submit button and if the date-picker2's date is lesser than date-picker1's date then alert dialog should come..

So what i am doing wrong, can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare `getTimeInMillis` of Calendar

```
Calendar mCalendarFirst = Calendar.getInstance();
mSelectedCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, your_year_from_frist_datepicker);
mSelectedCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, your_month_from_frist_datepicker);
mSelectedCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, your_day_from_frist_datepicker);

Calendar mCalendarSecond = Calendar.getInstance();
mSelectedCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, your_year_from_second_datepicker);
mSelectedCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, your_month_from_seconf_datepicker);
mSelectedCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, your_day_from_second_datepicker);

if(mCalendarSecond.getTimeInMillis() <= mCalendarFirst.getTimeInMillis())
{
        //Your second date is less than first date
        //Show your dialog here.
}
```

**Update:**

For your situation use below:

```
if(Code.DueDate.getTimeInMillis() <= Code.AssignDate.getTimeInMillis())
{
        //Your second date is less than first date
        //Show your dialog here.
}
```

**Try Below code:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.submit:

            Code.title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
            Code.description = editTextDesc.getText().toString().trim();

            Code.diff = Code.DueDate.getTimeInMillis()
                    - Code.AssignDate.getTimeInMillis();
            Code.days = Code.diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            Code.strDays = String.valueOf(Code.days);

            Date assignDate = new Date(Code.AssignDate.getTimeInMillis());
            Date dueDate = new Date(Code.DueDate.getTimeInMillis());

            if (Code.DueDate.getTimeInMillis() <= Code.AssignDate.getTimeInMillis()){
                AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBattery = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Assignment_Create.this);
                myDialogBattery.setTitle("How to use Less Battery");
                myDialogBattery.setMessage("hahahahahaha");
                myDialogBattery.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            }
                        });
                myDialogBattery.show();
            }else
            {
                if (isEdit) {
                    this.dataManipulator = new DataManipulator(this);
                    this.dataManipulator.update(updateId);
                    this.dataManipulator.close();
                } else {
                    this.dataManipulator = new DataManipulator(this);
                    this.dataManipulator.insert(Code.title, Code.description,
                            Code.strDays);
                    this.dataManipulator.close();
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Details are saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Assignment Created Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Assignment_Create.this.finish();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See my edited question above, i have set Activity like this, then how can i check this condition with my code.

Comment: I have tried this too but this is not working instead of alert dialog it is finishing my activity and shwing -2 or -1 days in list-view...

Comment: That's why i have posted my full code. I don't know what other mistake i am doing.

Comment: Yes, same way i am doing, but not getting alert dialog.

Comment: Print both date of getTimeInMillis and check is it going in if condition or not...

Comment: I did, and i got assignDate : Mon Dec 23 16:54:22 IST 2013
dueDate : Fri Dec 20 16:54:22 IST 2013 this output.

Comment: Print **Code.DueDate.getTimeInMillis()** && **Code.AssignDate.getTimeInMillis()** before this line **if (Code.DueDate.getTimeInMillis() <= Code.AssignDate.getTimeInMillis())**

Comment: getting output in milliseconds. =====dueDate====1387539398165
=====assignDate====1387798598164 and still alert dialog is not coming.

Comment: assignDate is greater than dueDate, then how it will come in loop? let me know again when you want dialog?? if **assignDate is greater than dueDate** or **dueDate is greater than assignDate**??

Comment: when dueDate is lesser than assign date.. eg if assign-date is 23-12-2013 then duedate should always greater than 23-12-2013. So i want alert if dueDate is lesser than 23-12-2013.

Comment: then code is perfect... print both Code.DueDate.getTimeInMillis() and Code.DueDate.getTime() and also Code.assignDate.getTimeInMillis() and Code.assignDate.getTime()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43752/discussion-between-innocent-killer-and-capdroid)

Comment: Thank you, i was doing some silly other mistake, otherwise your code was perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try following code. Here `firstDate` and `secondDate` are Date object

```
if (firstDate.after(secondDate)) { OR //secondDate.before(firstDate)

    //display alert here

} else {

}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: make sure by toast or log that your condition becomes true or not.

Comment: I suggest you to debug and see why your cursor doesn't go inside if statement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43747/discussion-between-ketan-and-innocent-killer)