# How do I set the date for a date picker?

Tags: android

I use `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` that's works fine.

I want to add date for 120 days in date picker.

What I mean is if I add 120 days, the date and month will be change automatically. 
How to do it?

Comment: Get the date form the date picker into a variable of type `Calendar`.  Add 120 days to it, then set the new date back into the DatePicker.

Comment: ya , i get value in calender as Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);but how to add 120 days from it

Comment: c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 120);

Comment: I posted an answer that, I hope, addresses what you are asking for.

Comment: This was asked before.. here is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421874/how-to-get-the-date-set-in-the-datepicker-widget-in-android

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(datepick.getYear(), datepick.getMonth() + 1, datepick.getDayOfMonth());
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 120);
datepick.updateDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1, cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create a date object with 120 days added (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747490/android-get-date-before-7-days-one-week) on how to do that) and use that to populate your datepicker, either on initialization or when changed. I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve however the latter doesn't seem right usability wise. In that case I would create an extra textfield that represents the +120 days date.

Answer (score 0):

Set Date Programmatically by using UpdateDate

```
datePickerDialog.UpdateDate(selectedDate ?? DateTime.Now);
```